# Flexbox aligning divs in the same row issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, material-ui

I'm trying to align a card header and a icon menu in the same row within a card component using flexbox, For some reason its not working , what I'm I missing? 
The result I keep getting:[image]
My css:

```
.flexItem {
  margin:  6px;
  flex:1;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.cardFlexContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 90vw;
  border:1px solid tomato;
}


.cardFlexItem {
  flex:1;
}

.cardFlexItem1 {
  width: 60vw;
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.cardFlexItem2 {
  width:10vw;
   display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
   border:1px solid green;
}
```

And my component code:

```
    <div className = {`${flexItem}`}>
<Card className = {`${cardFlexContainer}`}>
<div className = {`${cardFlexItem} ${cardFlexItem1}`}>
  <CardHeader
    title= {props.prize.title}
    subtitle = {props.prize.details}/>
    </div>
<div className = {`${cardFlexItem} ${cardFlexItem2}`}>
    {rightIconMenu}
    </div>
</Card>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say align them, are you trying to center both of them? How do you want them aligned?

Comment: I mean instead of 2 rows within the card , I want 1 row with cardFlexItem1(cardHeader) and then cardFlexItem2(icon menu)

Comment: I've tried to replicate your code in [codepen](http://codepen.io/bbodien/pen/pEZZjZ?editors=1100#0), but it doesn't look like your picture. Can you help set it up so it's reproducing your problem, then I should be able to fix it.

Comment: I know its very strange, I can't reproduce it either on codepen, the problem I believe is with some inherent styling of material-ui components i'm using. I spent few hours debugging it, Can't seem to find the exact cause.

Comment: Is it hosted online anywhere?